# Ionic display contacts similar to local device contact list

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have an Ionic app that I'm developing, where I need to have a customized contacts list.

I want to display it similar to the local device contact display where a user can scroll to a alphabetized group by clicking on a letter on a vertical list to the right of all entries.

Anyone seen any good examples of this?

Again, using Ionic / Cordova

Comment: Thanks Hard. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these link. It has ion-alpha-scroll that you are looking for.

[ion-alpha-scroll](https://github.com/aquint/ion-alpha-scroll)

Regards.

Comment: Here's the Ionic 2 version for anyone else who may stumble upon this: https://github.com/rossmartin/ionic2-alpha-scroll